# How can I select data from one table depending on the data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: **contracts_main_list** and **contracts_detail**.
In contracts_main_list I have columns:

```
user_id
contract_id
```

and in contracts_detail:

```
contract_id
other columns with data
```

I need to select all the rows from the table contracts_main_list `WHERE user_id = some number`.
From these rows I need to get the list of contract numbers (from column `contract_id`) and according to them select rows corresponding to each of the contract number from the list. So something like:

```
WHERE contracts_detail.contract_id = contracts_main_list.contract_id
```

The contract_ids are probably gonna be unique, but in case there is some kind of error and there will be more rows with the same contract_id in either of the tables, I need to select only one row (so probably using DISTINCT) and select the latest record (both tables have a column id as a primary key)

Also if there is no row in contracts_detail matching with the contract_id to the contract_id of the first table `contracts_main_list` it should skip the row. But I guess the condition:

> WHERE contracts_detail.contract_id = contracts_main_list.contract_id

already covers it.

I hope I made it clear enough. What I am trying to do in real life is show list of contracts with all the relevant data belonging to the user.

To sum this up, I need to find all the contracts belonging to the user and select the rows with details about each contract and finally get the data from the contracts_detail table as a result.

Comment: MySQL. Does it support this?

Comment: How come the comments have disappeared here?

Comment: You can delete your own comment when it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result you're looking for:

```
SELECT CD.*
FROM (SELECT C2.contract_id
            ,MAX(C2.id) AS last_main_list_id 
            ,MAX(CD2.id) AS last_contracts_detail_id
      FROM contracts_main_list C2
      INNER JOIN contracts_detail CD2 ON CD2.contract_id = C2.contract_id
      GROUP BY C2.contract_id) L
INNER JOIN contracts_main_list C ON C.id = L.last_main_list_id
                                   AND C.user_id = ?
INNER JOIN contracts_detail CD ON CD.id= L.last_contracts_detail_id
```

This query use a subquery for the `FROM` because of the following indication you provided:

> The contract_ids are probably gonna be unique, but in case there is
>   some kind of error and there will be more rows with the same
>   contract_id in either of the tables, I need to select only one row

If you're sure that the `contract_id` are unique, here is the same query without this check on `contract_id`:

```
SELECT CD.*
FROM contracts_main_list C
INNER JOIN contracts_detail CD ON CD.contract_id = C.contract_id
WHERE C.user_id = ?
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Joel. This very helpful. I already assigned unique keys to the "id" columns so there will be no duplicities in the first place and I can use the second simpler solution.